# I need to block user to edit newsletter HTML area any one have solution ?

Tags: html, email, gmail, newsletter

I Need a solution for the problem below .

IF i send a HTML based newsletter to my donors and they can forward it to any other his friends , but at that time i don't want that user can edit the HTMl area,

If any solution kindly know me thanks !

Comment: If they want to commit fraud by sending people things they pretend came from you originally, there's not much you can do to stop them. If it's really bad, maybe go to the police.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to stop them from editing the html. The only option you have is to put it in an image. Large images are not really recommended for email, so you'll have to make a decision on what is more important.